# Toaster Oven pan Without The Toaster Oven

Tags: equipment, cleaning, pan

Growing up, my parents had a couple of little, 2 layer pans that came with Toast-R-Ovens (The appliance themselves had been lost or broke, but the pans remained.). They were great for cooking drippy things, and fit in the dishwasher beautifully.

I would like a couple or 3 of those pans, but I don't really need a toaster oven, and I certainly don't need 3. It there a place I can get those pans or ones like them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I regularly see them in the catalogs that come to the house all the time. If you are looking for a pan in which a rack sets into, try Walter Drake at this link:

http://www.wdrake.com/WalterDrake/Shopping/ProductDetail.aspx?CID=Kitchen&SCID=Food+Preparation&ProductID=0000136379&SourceCode=20509000001&mr:trackingCode=6726E407-C781-DE11-B7F3-0019B9C043EB&mr:referralID=NA

They also have a few other toaster oven pans that may interest you.

Comment: Ok, My google-fu is weak. Thanks. I was searching for an exact brand and not finding it.

Answer (score 0):

Simply find a cooling rack that fits in a jelly roll pan.  Line jelly roll pan with foil (or determine to clean all the drips afterwards), set cooling rack in pan, set food on rack, cook.

Comment: That's what I have been using. But the jelly roll pan does not fit conveniently in the dish washer, and its non-stick layer is coming off from having meat drippings thoroughly baked onto it.

Comment: @Matthew - the meat drippings are why I line my jelly roll pan with foil.  I have a pretty small jelly roll pan too, perhaps a smaller one would work?  If all else fails, stores do sell toaster oven racks - try looking around online.